# CamelCase vs snake_case vs dash-s in Ember.js app

Tags: ember.js

I could not find any clear guidance on where to use CamelCase vs snake_case vs dash-s in different parts of Ember.js application.

Which one of the cases below is recommended and what be an impact if I replace one with another?

```
this.route('favoriteAuthor')
this.route('favorite_author')
this.route('favorite-author')

this.modelFor('favoriteAuthor')
this.modelFor('favorite_author')
this.modelFor('favorite-author')

this.get('store').find('favoriteAuthor')
this.get('store').find('favorite_author')
this.get('store').find('favorite-author')

{{render 'favoriteAuthor'}}
{{render 'favorite_author'}}
{{render 'favorite-author'}}

this.controllerFor('favoriteAuthor')
this.controllerFor('favorite_author')
this.controllerFor('favorite-author')

this.transitionTo('favoriteAuthor')
this.transitionTo('favorite_author')
this.transitionTo('favorite-author')
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

camelCase-s are for model, controller, route it's convection for javaScript. Dashes are for handlebars helpers(before they was also camelCase). snake_case are use for parameters like post_id ... photo_id and etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you know, ember works a lot on magic pixie dust around naming conventions.  A not-so-well documented aspect of this is that if you use snake_case on your template names, they will automap against CamelCase route names.  For example:

```
App.SampleTestRoute = Ember.Route.extend();
```

Will automatically render a template with the name:

```
"sample_test"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, that is the only part which is almost clear. "Almost" because it would also work with template named "sample-test". Not sure what would be the difference though...